# Word implicitly containing the meaning of bad effect in cause

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is there any proper word that already implicitly contains the meaning of bad effect instead of the bring about / cause ?

For example...

> A can bring about unexpected detriment occurring in addition to the desired effect of the policy

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please include more context -- the circumstances in which you'd use the word, specific situation in which it would be useful?

Comment: we introduced a specific policy with a good intention, but unfortunately, it is found that it can be abused by someone.

Comment: Our policy has an unforeseen downside that allows it to be abused.

Comment: Double-edged sword; perverse effect; camel's nose under the tent; unintended consequences; cobra/rat effect (bounty on rats led not to their elimination but to the farming of rats).  "unintended consequences" is widely used in the literature on social and economic poiicy.  For a single term, double-edged sword may be closest.

Comment: @JaeHyukLee Consider [*side effect*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/side_effect). But regarding [your comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377325/word-implicitly-containing-the-meaning-of-bad-effect-in-cause#comment885238_377325), isn't that usually the case? All policies constrain behaviour, otherwise there wouldn't be any point to having them. The constraints produce winners and losers, hence the potential for abuse.